# Conditionally assign classes to a PrimeNG p-datatable row group header

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to conditionally assign a css class to a row group header that's from PrimeNG's p-datatable.

I've tried using ngClass inside of the ng-template tag but that doesn't work because the rowData object is undefined. Here's what that looks like:

`[ngClass]="rowData.isNewObject? 'objects-added' : 'objects-existing'"`

Note that I'm trying to style the group header itself, not the rows that are being grouped.

Here is the general idea of what I'm working with:

```
<p-dataTable 
    [value]="tableData" 
    sortField="!isNewObject" 
    rowGroupMode="subheader" 
    groupField="isNewObject">

    <ng-template 
      pTemplate="rowgroupheader" 
      let-rowData>
      {{rowData.isNewObject == true ? "NEW OBJECTS" : "EXISTING OBJECTS"}}
    </ng-template>
    <p-column field="isNewObject" header="Is Object New?"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Thank you for your time.